# Calculate average percentile and typical deviation with logic

Tags: statistics

The following table reflects the delay, in minutes, experienced by the low cost *"lowcost airlines"* last year

```
Delay  |  Number of flights
0-10   | 160
10-20  | 240
20-40  | 280
40- 60 | 120
```

(a) What is the average delay per flight?

(b) Calculate the minimum delay that a flight may experience to be within 42% of the flights with the greatest delay.

(c) Let us suppose that in the *"Travel airline"*, the average flight delay was 15 minutes with a typical deviation of 12 minutes. In which of the two airlines is the delay more homogeneous? Reason the answer

I have doubts since the intervals are given every 10 minutes and every 20. I add the number of flights from 0-20 **It is correct to do that?? I will not be losing data from the observations?** to group it to 400 and I get the following table

```
Class | ni  | Ci  | Ci*ni  |  Ni
0-20  | 400 | 10  | 4000   |  400
20-40 | 280 | 30  | 8400   |  680
40-60 | 120 | 50  | 6000   |  800
        800         18400
```

The average is 18400/800= 23 minute

b) Asks for the 58th percentile, so

```
P20 = 20+ ((0,58*800)-400)*20 /280 = 24,57 minute
```

c)I calculate the typical deviation of the data I have from the variance

```
class   | ni-(Ci^2)
0-20    | 40000
20-40   | 252000
40-60   | 300000
           592000

S^2 = (592000/800) -(23^2) = 211
```

To calculate the typical deviation I calculate the square root of the variance and it gives me 14,52 minute.

If I compare with the line of 15 minutes of average delay and 12 of typical deviation, it has a better pint than having 23 minutes on average and 14.52 of deviation. Is that the reasoning?

Comment: (a) About all you can do toward estimating the sample mean $\bar X$ is to use the formula $\bar X \approx \frac 1 n \sum_{j=0}^4 f_jm_j,$ where the counts $f_j$ are 160, 240, 280, 120, the midpoints $m_j$ are 5, 15, 20, 50, and $n$ is the sum of the counts. Once you have $\bar X,$ you can do something similar to get the sample variance $S^2.$ _Do not_ combine intervals, that results in loss of info, and you have little enough as it is. // (b) note that the median is about 20, (c) Does 'typical deviation' mean standard deviation? If so maybe compare $S$ (not $S^2$) from (a) with 15.

Comment: I got $\bar X \approx 23.5,\, S^2 \approx 210.5,\, S \approx 14.5,$ which are close to what you got. So, if I understand your last paragraph, you're on the right track for (c).